# Swift: can properties be required based on another property being set?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to re-use a single viewcontroller but re-purposed slightly and I'm wondering if there is a structured way to require some properties to be set based on another property.

`For example assume that the viewcontroller has the following properties
- var displayMode: DisplayMode // see below
- var id: Int
- var description: String
- var name: String`

If we are in quickView mode then I expect a ID and Description values to be set.
Else if we are in defaultView mode I expect the Name property to be set.

```
enum DisplayMode {
    case quickView
    case defaultView
}
```

Obviously I could just set those and expect them to be set but I'm wondering if there is a structured Swift-like way of forcing this, like having the properties nested in the DisplayMode type?

Comment: How required you want it to be? Crash your app on `viewDidLoad` if values is not set?

Comment: @michael-hudson : Stuff like these becomes fairly straight forward if u use reactive programming frameworks like Reactive-Cocoa or RxSwift.

Comment: @Tj3n NRitH's answer seems to satisfy my 'requirement' essentially I was hoping it could be embedded such that when I set the displayMode the values also need to be set

Comment: @SandeepBhandari That's good to know, thanks I will have a look at those frameworks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [associated values](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html) for your `enum` cases, like so:

```
enum DisplayMode {
    case quickview(id: Int, description: String)
    case defaultview(name: String)
}
```

This forces the user to provide valid associated values whenever a `DisplayMode` variable is declared:

```
var mode = DisplayMode.quickView(id: 11, description: "Prosecco")
```

To get the associated values back out, you bind them to variables in your `switch`:

```
switch mode {
case let .quickView(id, description):
    // do something with id and description
case let .defaultview(name):
    // do something with name
}
```

By using associated values, you wouldn't have to declare stand-alone properties (i.e. object variables) for `id`, `description`, or `name`.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of associated values but this looks like exactly what I'm after! I also appreciate the side note; my actual use case is a little more complicated - my example was a contrived demo but that's a good catch and I will update for future users that come here

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this is what you want:

```
var displayMode: DisplayMode {
    didSet {
        if displayMode == quickview {
            // self.id = whatever
            // do whatever else you want
        }
        else if displayMode == default {
            // self.id = whatever
            // do whatever else you want
        }
    }
}

var id: Int
var description: String
var name: String
```

(Edit: Of course, it'd be a little different because you're using an enum, but you get the gist of it.)

Another option might be to use KVO. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html